# Scrapy spider: Download all images from img src

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I scraped some links from a website and I'm using scrapy spider for scraping purpose.

```
 # image urls
        look_inside_image_urls = response.xpath('//ul[@class="list-unstyled pages"]/li').extract_first()

        for i in look_inside_image_urls:
            print("============> look_inside_image_urls ===============>", i)
```

But I got none type value. Just I am any number of image link of li. I download via loop.

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="lookInsideDiv" style="display: block;">
                <div class="exitBtn"><i class="ion-close-round"></i></div>
                <div class="pagesArea">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled pages">
                        
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/fc955fd4b_117698-1.jpg"></li>
                        
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/11f94595e_117698-2.jpg"></li>
                        
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/555959ec2_117698-3.jpg"></li>
                        
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/81b071d0c_117698-4.jpg"></li>
                        
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/30ef8b806_117698-5.jpg"></li>
                        
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/6cb40391f_117698-6.jpg"></li>
                        
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/a41c97880_117698-7.jpg"></li>
                        
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/d1a4bff6e_117698-8.jpg"></li>
                        
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/9503cfda1_117698-9.jpg"></li>
                        
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/54f1774ee_117698-10.jpg"></li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I just want to get all link inside li like this

```
https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/fc955fd4b_117698-1.jpg
https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/fc955fd4b_117698-1.jpg
https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/fc955fd4b_117698-1.jpg
https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/fc955fd4b_117698-1.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, to extract the all image use extract() (its return list) instead of extract_first()(return first item) method.

```
look_inside_image_urls = response.xpath('//ul[@class="list-unstyled pages"]/li/img/@src').extract()

for i in look_inside_image_urls:
    print("============> look_inside_image_urls ===============>", i)
```

**Edit**

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

html ="""<div class="lookInsideDiv" style="display: block;">
                <div class="exitBtn"><i class="ion-close-round"></i></div>
                <div class="pagesArea">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled pages">
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/fc955fd4b_117698-1.jpg"></li>
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/11f94595e_117698-2.jpg"></li>
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/555959ec2_117698-3.jpg"></li>
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/81b071d0c_117698-4.jpg"></li>
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/30ef8b806_117698-5.jpg"></li>
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/6cb40391f_117698-6.jpg"></li>
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/a41c97880_117698-7.jpg"></li>
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/d1a4bff6e_117698-8.jpg"></li>
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/9503cfda1_117698-9.jpg"></li>
                            <li><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/54f1774ee_117698-10.jpg"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>"""


data = Selector(text=html)
look_inside_image_urls = data.xpath('//*/ul[@class="list-unstyled pages"]/li/img/@src').extract()
for i in look_inside_image_urls:
    print("============> look_inside_image_urls ===============>", i)


============> look_inside_image_urls ===============> https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/fc955fd4b_117698-1.jpg
============> look_inside_image_urls ===============> https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/11f94595e_117698-2.jpg
============> look_inside_image_urls ===============> https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/555959ec2_117698-3.jpg
============> look_inside_image_urls ===============> https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/81b071d0c_117698-4.jpg
============> look_inside_image_urls ===============> https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/30ef8b806_117698-5.jpg
============> look_inside_image_urls ===============> https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/6cb40391f_117698-6.jpg
============> look_inside_image_urls ===============> https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/a41c97880_117698-7.jpg
============> look_inside_image_urls ===============> https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/d1a4bff6e_117698-8.jpg
============> look_inside_image_urls ===============> https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/9503cfda1_117698-9.jpg
============> look_inside_image_urls ===============> https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/rokomari110/LookInside20190827/54f1774ee_117698-10.jpg
```

Comment: it is return [] , nothing

Comment: response.xpath('//ul[@class="list-unstyled pages"]/li/img/@src').extract() ues this

Comment: x = response.xpath('//ul[@class="list-unstyled pages"]/li/img/@src').extract() it returnd [], nohting, you could check it

Comment: could you please provide the url link.

Comment: https://www.rokomari.com/book/117698/mosnobie-rumi-5

Comment: please follow this link https://pasteboard.co/JMmjUBu.png

Comment: Are your sure? there are exists such type of image. I have checked and not found that type of image. after use this xpath i have found image url . You can try it. response.xpath('//ul[@class="list-unstyled pages"]/li/img/@data-src').extra
    ...: ct()

Comment: Yes It is working. but I would like to get amzon s3 link  not this, it is possible? ['fc955fd4b_117698-1.jpg', '11f94595e_117698-2.jpg', '555959ec2_117698-3.jpg', '81b071d0c_117698-4.jpg', '30ef8b806_117698-5.jpg', '6cb40391f_117698-6.jpg', 'a41c97880_117698-7.jpg', 'd1a4bff6e_117698-8.jpg', '9503cfda

Comment: if exists image then posibile.Please Upvote or accept this/any Answer which is useful to you

Comment: sure. but How can I get image link(amazone s3 link)?